# "What really am" or "What I really am" - which is more appropriate

Tags: word-choice, clauses, ellipsis, parallelism

Which statement is more appropriate?

> 1. Is that what really am?
> 2. Is that what **I** really am?

And instead of "what", can I use "how" and have the same meaning?

The person saying the statement thinks of himself as something like a coward, then he questions himself. I was thinking "Is that what I really am?" was more appropriate because "am" is always used with "I" but I'm not sure. "Is that what really am?" sounds fine to me too.

Comment: you need to provide us with more information. Clarify the context. This question, what it is now, is too broad to answer.

Comment: In the context, the person telling the statement thinks of himself as something like a coward. And then he asks himself. I was thinking "Is that what I really am?" was more appropriate because "am" as I know is always used with "I" but I'm not sure. And "Is that what really am?" seems sounds fine?

Comment: yes, that's clear now. Vote retracted.

Answer (score 5):

The first sentence is incorrect. You cannot leave out the *I*, otherwise you would have no subject in your subclause.

Your verb always needs a subject, unless it is in the imperative form. The subject van sometimes also be left out when your sentence has the same subject as another sentence: through ellipsis. For example:

> *He* **did** the dishes and **cleaned** the room.

Here your subject can be left out because both clauses are main clauses and the both have the same subject.

In your case, one clause is a main clause while the other is a subclause. Furthermore, your clauses do not have the same subject. That is why you cannot omit the subject, so the first sentence is incorrect.

Comment: Also, using 'how' would change the meaning here. The question with 'what' can have a broader answer, while 'how' can only have an answer about the way the person acts or about his/her personality.